# read access violation. this was 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, access-violation, this-pointer

I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong?  While debugging, `this` shows `0xcdcdcdcd {theDouble=??? }`so i know my variable isnt getting stored in my mutator.  How would i go about fixing this issue? Am I supposed initialize `this` somewhere? I am using visual studio by the way.
Thank you for the help.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    const int MAX = 4;
    CLASS **object = new CLASS*[MAX];
    string name = "todd";
    string aString = "words";
    double aDouble = 10.0;
    object[i]->setDouble(aDouble);
    return 0;
}

//.cpp
CLASS::Class()
{
    theDouble = new double;
    *theDouble = NULL;
}
CLASS::Class(double aDouble)
{
    *theDouble = aDouble;
}
void CLASS::setDouble(double p)
{
    *theDouble = p; 
double Class::getDouble()
{return (*theDouble);}

//.h
class CLASS
{
 protected:
    double *theDouble;
 public:
    Insurance();
    Insurance(double premium);
    //~Insurance();
    void setDouble(double p);
    double getDouble();
    string toString();
   };`
```

Comment: Why are you even using pointers in your program?  There is no need for them whatsoever.

Comment: You've created an array of pointers, but they don't point anywhere because you never created any objects for the pointers to actually point to. Pointers don't automatically create an object and point to it when you declare them, you have to assign the address of an object yourself.

Comment: You also have other problems, such as storing the address of a local variable, assigning `NULL` to a double, memory leaks, and the completely unnecessary use of pointers in the first place.

Comment: As of right now the program is incomplete but the pointers will be used, I'm just trying to get it to store the information first.

Comment: Chances are the pointers are still completely unnecessary. It's rare that one would have to use pointers in good C++ (unless you're implementing some data structure like a BST), and using raw pointers is even more rare.

Comment: *As of right now the program is incomplete but the pointers will be used* -- That's not how using pointers works.  Unless you write the pointer manipulation code to completion, then your program will not behave correctly.

Comment: *I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong?* -- Well, you've basically messed up how to handle dynamically allocated memory properly, memory leaks, etc.  That is done on multiple lines in the code you posted.

Comment: Sidenote: `0xCDCDCDCD` is [Microsoft-ese for uninitialized dynamic memory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_other_uses_)

Comment: Your compiler turns UB into a diagnosable error message, it is a reliable indication of using an uninitialized pointer.  object[i] = new CLASS; is missing.

Comment: Why `double *theDouble`, then `new double...` and not `double theDouble`? Why you need to define address for single variable.

Answer (score 1):

You use `CLASS`, `Class` and `Insurance` in mix where you should use one name so your posted code can not compile. I replace those with `IronMan`.

What you see as `0xCDCDCDCD` is not `this` pointer value but value of the pointer member `theDouble`. The issue comes from in constructor:

```
IronMan::IronMan(double aDouble)
{
    *theDouble = aDouble;
}
```

That constructor dereferences uninitialised member variable `theDouble` and
since debuggers tend to fill uninitialized memory with some bytes like `0xCD` you will have that as value of the pointer. Therefore you get a crash for accessing memory at such address.

One way out of it is to allocate memory for `theDouble`

```
IronMan::IronMan(double aDouble)
{
    theDouble = new double(aDouble);   
}
```

Better would be likely to avoid using pointers there at all but just have direct double data member:

```
protected:
    double theDouble;
```